# Get data posted by $.ajax via $request argument of Controller method

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm using the following code to post an array of objects to an api Controller.

```
$.ajax({
 url: "/api/links", 
 method:"post" , 
 data:  JSON.stringify(  this.results  )  , 
 contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
 context:this ,
 success:
  function(res){
     $("#res").html(res);
   }
});
```

The problem is $_POST array is empty while I could get the raw posted data using $raw = file_get_contents("php://input").
Somebody offered to use this:

```
$_POST = json_decode($rawdata, true);
```

It may fill the $_POST and solve the problem but I'm using Laravel so I'm supposed to use the $request (of type Request) parameter of Controller method not pure PHP. 
So I think there is a right and Laravel way for handling this.

By the way $rawdata is precisely what I've posted to the controller which is something like this:
[{"id":484,"LinkTitle":"contactus","URL":"https://url1..."},{"id":485,"LinkTitle":"faq","URL":"/faq"}]

I also tried wrapping it with {} before serializing in order to make it an object:

```
JSON.stringify(  {"myData":this.results}  )
```

This way $_POST array was filled but not in a normal way.
All I want is to access LinkTitle via $_POST which means I would be able to use $request argument passed to controller's method so i can do other things like validation etc...

EDIT : Like @AmeyaJoshi said it's array of objects and not just object/array. So I can't get it via $_POST["LinkTitle"] . All I said here is because I imagine if $_POST is populated correctly then I can use $request to validate and save my records at once via eloquent.Thank you

EDIT2: I tried removing stringify like 
katsarov said and result of print_r($_POST,true) is

```
Array
(
    [undefined]  =>; 
)
```

and result of dd($request->all()) is

```
array:1 [▼
  "undefined" => null
]
```

Comment: Are you getting data in $_POST["myData"] ?
Because, considering your data structure , $_POST["LinkTitle"] is not possible.. LinkTitle is key in object and you are sending array of objects. So you will have to run loop on this array first.

Comment: My mistake..You are absolutely right. I just want to get them one by one via a loop around $request and validate and save them at once via eloquent

Answer (score 0):

It is simple :)

- Don't stringify data object
- request()->get('LinkTitle') (or $request
  if you have it in the method)

Comment: I tried it and it returns Array
(
    [undefined] => 
)

Comment: You may tray dd($request->all()). It will dump all data which your ajax is sending and based on that info you can the data that you need

Comment: I tried it without stringify and result of dd($request->all()) is array:1 [▼
  "undefined" => null
]

Comment: Check this.results in JS, you may not have it defined. Try to replace it with simple array, then submit and check again $request->all(). You should have your data. Then find why you don't have this.results in JS

Comment: I have it in js. As I said I can get posted raw data.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your data structure , `$_POST["LinkTitle"]` is not possible.. `LinkTitle` is key in object and you are sending array of objects. So  to access `LinktTitle` key you will have to run loop on this array first.